# Are seeds in melons and other fruits good to eat?

Tags: fruit, seeds, melon

I usually throw away seeds in melons (and other fruits) and I paradoxically buy different seeds from the store. Are seeds in such things good to eat and where can I use them? Because they are not dry, how can I store for future dishes? Do they have the same nutritional profile as other seeds for sale?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer, but I saw a video-recipe for a Nigerian strew made with "Egusi." I looked it up and interestingly, they are the seeds of a specific gourd. The gourd itself is apparently inedible, and is only cultivated for the seeds.

Comment: Very disappointed that no answers claiming a watermelon plant would grow in your innards has been offered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few seeds which are good to eat. These generally get sold in the supermarket (pumpkin seeds, apricot kernels). If you buy the fruit containing them, you can keep the seeds.

If you want to store them, you should dry them first. Spread the cleaned seeds in a single layer on paper and put it in a warm dry place (not in direct sunlight), and wait a few days. You should deshell them right before consuming, that way they keep longer. If you want to eat them right away, don't dry them. They taste better when fresh. Some should be roasted in the shell before eaten (pumpkin seeds, sunflower seeds).

There is little sense in eating seeds not commonly sold in supermarkets, like melon seeds or apple pips. They don't have any nutritional value for humans, or taste bad (e.g. very bitter), or both. It is even dangerous to experiment too much. For example, peach kernels contain poisonous cyanide compounds. So stick to what is commonly eaten, there is a reason the other seeds aren't used.

Comment: +1 I have never thought of such difference between apricot and peach! I doubt whether I could even differentiate them, I just buy them if they are cheap enough. It is very hard for me to say difference between peach [here](http://www.wuchi.co.uk/pictures/ind4525b0acaa279l.jpg) and apricot [here](http://www.kandlekaz.com.au/images/apricot%20kernel.jpg). Apricot sometimes is a bit more yellow and smaller (but this is poor difference as the pictures reveal). Why pumpkin and apricot seeds are eatable? Is it possible to notice it by tasting? Can you say eatable seed from colour or some other char.?

Comment: There's not such a great difference between apricot and peach kernels, both contain cyanide. But then so do all of these: cherries, plums, almonds, peaches, apricots, crabapples, apples, mangos, and bitter almonds. If eaten raw, and the seeds chewed, and eaten in large quantities, then there may be some risk from these seeds. However, most people roast the seeds before eating. This cooking process effectively removes and danger of poisoning.

Comment: @Rincewind42, I have read somewhere that the concentration in peach kernels is much higher than in apricot kernels and other seeds. It doesn't mean that somebody will keel over just because they ate 2-3 kernels (or 20-30), but still, I was advised against eating them. But I don't remember where I read that, or what the actual concentration of cyanide in different kernels is.

Comment: @hhh There is a huge difference in taste between apricots and peaches, and as you say, the color and size is different. But I guess there is no reason to make the difference if you don't need it for anything. As for which seeds are OK to eat, take a look at what seeds are being sold. If nobody sells a seed, there is nobody willing to eat it. If nobody wants to eat it, there must be a reason for it. But if a seed is available to be bought (like apricot kernels), then it is OK to save it from the fruit you buy.

Comment: @Rincewind42 - I had read that the edibility of apricot seeds is directly related to the cultivar - sweet kernels are commonly used for oil and other confections, but the bitter kernels contain more cyanide and can be dangerous.  I don't know if the apricots sold might be sweet- or bitter- seeded, or are labeled if both are sold, but that might be quite important to know if one wants to use their seeds.

Comment: @rumtscho "If nobody wants to eat it, there must be a reason for it." That is a systemically-false principle for how to determine whether something is safe to eat. A wide variety of garden weeds (purslane, lamb's-quarters, goosefoot) are perfectly edible leaf vegetables, highly palatable. Poor public education, combined with their "weed" reputation,  keeps them out of stores. Apricot kernels, on the other hand, are marketed as a sham treatment for cancer *because of* their potential toxicity. http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/05/12/eating-apricot-kernels-can-kill-you-government-warns/

Comment: @Megha - It's true that apricot seeds come in multiple varieties of varying cyanide content; however, that is just as true of all other *Prunus* species, plums and peaches included. Moreover, relying on natural variation is an inconsistent way of avoiding cyanide. Only almonds have been specifically bred for a cyanide-free nut / pit. (The wild, bitter variety contains cyanide, but its traditional flavoring use involves processing to remove this.)

Answer (score 12):

In Northern India, we eat Musk Melon and Water Melon seeds. In fact they are used like nuts. We make sweet dish too.
The de-kernelling process is done by hand at home, which is quite lengthy.

We deseed melon. Put the seeds to dry for approximatively 2 days; with fingers or tweezers, break the kernel and get the yummy seed. Of course, it can be stored for months, if dried properly, and for years, if kept in freezer.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer says that seeds not commonly sold in stores have no nutrition, are bitter, or are poisonous.  This is incorrect.

Watermelon, cantaloupe, apple, peach, apricot, and so forth seeds are packed full of nutrients; even more than most commercially sold seeds.

Watermelon seeds are one of my top favorites, and are loaded with vital compounds, one being zinc. They are crunchy, and taste nutty. They are delicious!

Cantaloupe seeds have been eaten by other cultures for years, and studies show they are full of good stuff too.

Also, apricot seeds which are bitter, are said to be poisonous because they contain hydrogen cyanide. Although this is true, it is such a small dose that it takes 70 apricot kernels to be lethal [editors note:  probably mean lethal dose in full sized adults].

Many cultures, like turkey adore apricot seeds; they simply don't eat too many. Studies also show that the small amount of cyanide is beneficial to our immune systems.

Do you know that apple, cherry, peach, apricot, almond or anything else in this family produces cyanide?  Guess what cyanide tastes like? Almonds! That's right, our beloved almonds contain cyanide too!

Comment: According to [this site](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/05/certain-almonds-are-highly-poisonous/) about 0.68mg per lb body weight constitutes a lethal dose of cyanide. If each (raw) bitter almond contains 4-9mg of hydrogen cyanide, then it only takes 13-30 kernels to kill an adult of my size (~180lb). It would only take 3-7 kernels to kill your average 5 year old (~40lb).

Answer (score 2):

My wife's family is from Peru and they tend to eat the seeds of things that I would typically avoid.  Look at fruits like grenadillas or tunas (more commonly known here as the prickly pear) and the granada (pomegranate).  I had a friend who used to eat the entire apple and, while the seeds are considered poisonous it would take a large amount to affect you.  All of this said, I don't like the texture of the seeds so use your judgement and do a bit of research.  You may find that the seeds add an interesting element to your foods.

Comment: pomegranate is normally eaten in Europe too

Comment: I live in the Southwestern US and prickly pear is eaten here. Usually the seeds are strained out though.

Answer (score 1):

I used the seeds of a honeydew melon in my daily green power smoothie. I found pulverized in the high powered blender made the bitter kale taste disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Pumpkin seeds roasted with a little of salty water is a great (and commonly sold and home made in México) snack. They are also used along with sunflower seeds in preparing some hot sauces and Mole (the hard way). Seeds of Cantaloupe (melon) and Watermelon can be blendend along with their edible parts to strengthen flavor and keep freshness when preparing fruit flavored/fresh water ("Agua fresca"). When watermelon seeds are really small, you can eat and chew them along with the fruit: they are usually sweet.

Answer (score 0):

There's no harm in eating the fruits of a melon, or fruit. It just passes through your system completely.

You probably can't store them for future usage, as only ripe seeds are eaten, and most seeds from a melon don't ripen until the melon rots.

Comment: I think the question is about intentionally eating seeds and chewing them up so they don't just pass through.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to find watermelons with seeds in your local market or supermarket,you’re in luck,but if you can’t,I suggest you to buy the seeds of them... My recipe is to use the watermelon seeds and blend them with your seedless watermelon(2 or 3 slices of them) and turn on your Ninja or Nutribullet... You won’t regret,it tastes delicious and you’ll have a really healthy prostate.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to pumpkins, there's a variety called [kakai](https://www.chilternseeds.co.uk/item_1363g_pumpkin_kakai_seeds) that has hull-less seeds, easier to prepare and good to eat (the flesh is quite good too).   Melon seeds can be treated in the same way. Melons and pumpkinsa are in fact very closely related.

You can simply clean and dry them, but generally they're nicer toasted in the oven, perhaps with some spice (or salt, or honey).  Once *very* dry, or toasted, they will keep for months in an airtight container in a cool place, though if I toast homegrown pumpkin seeds they're normally eaten in a week.