# Santa Claus melon seeds

Tags: seeds, melon

Just had a bit of a spook from my Brother. Ate some piel de sapo melon seeds and he said they are toxic. Are they? Should I be worried?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16440/are-seeds-in-melons-and-other-fruits-good-to-eat

Comment: If you're worried you might have eaten something toxic, call your local poison control center, don't ask random people on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

I can find no evidence via internet search that the seeds of Piel de Sapo melons have any toxicity whatsoever.

Even if they did, eating a handful of seeds would be harmless.  For example, while apple seeds are definitely toxic, [you have to eat several dozen of them](https://www.healthline.com/health/food-nutrition/are-apple-seeds-poisonous) to feel any ill effects.

Answer (score 0):

Melon seeds, like pumpkin seeds, can be [toasted and eaten as a snack](https://www.bbc.com/food/melon_seeds). Recipes don't warn about a need to reach high heat, so there's no reason to think they wouldn't be safe raw. And your melon is a variety of normal melon, not something exotic to be concerned about